# Can't deploy stream or task in Spring Cloud Data Flow successfully

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a spark cluster in yarn mode, and I installed Spring Cloud Data Flow on the master node directly, followed the simple steps of the document, everything goes well.
I created simple stream and task, deployed them, nothing happened there.

`stream create ticktock --definition “time | log” --deploy

task create --name pi --definition "spark-yarn --spark.app-jar=<spark-example.jar> --spark.assembly-jar=<spark-assembly-jar-in-hdfs> --spark.app-class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi"`

In webUI I can see the stream is deployed and the task is in unknown status. But in the console of yarn-server, something abnormal printed as following:

`2017-02-04 02:26:14.736  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:14.737  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:14.738  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:14.740  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:19.998  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Checking status of ticktock:time:application_1486192446476_0003
2017-02-04 02:26:19.998  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.000  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.005  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.007  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.008  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Checking status of ticktock:log:application_1486192446476_0003
2017-02-04 02:26:20.009  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.010  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.011  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:20.013  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.268  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Checking status of ticktock:time:application_1486192446476_0003
2017-02-04 02:26:25.268  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.270  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.274  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.276  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.277  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Checking status of ticktock:log:application_1486192446476_0003
2017-02-04 02:26:25.277  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.279  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.280  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa
2017-02-04 02:26:25.281  INFO 4940 --- [nio-9393-exec-3] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@72feb9aa`

I think it means that the stream and task are not deployed successfully, right? How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your problem description doesn't include all the details. Perhaps you could edit the post and supply some of the details as listed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/wiki/Reporting-Issues)? Also, we are addressing the Spark-task issue - see [spring-cloud-task-app-starters/spark-yarn#3](https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/spark-yarn/pull/3) for more details.

Comment: @SabbyAnandan, Thank you for your reply.  
Actually I've got stream work successfully now, but I can not find the log module output using spring cloud dataflow for yarn when I tried the stream " time | log ". However, the stream " time | file " or " http | hdfs " works well. Never mind, I think the stream part works well now, it might be even better if you could tell me why the log module didn't show the log file path.   
The task part still can't submit it's job to spark-yarn, I'll read the link you supplied and have a try again.

Comment: I have one more question about spark-yarn module, I see the modification of spark version 1.6.3, does it mean that it can only submit to spark cluster 1.6.3 in yarn mode or it can also support the latter versions?

Comment: Please consider opening a new thread on this.